# How do I use custom variables in MSBuild scripts?

Tags: msbuild

Is there a way to use custom variables on the command-line when building with MSBuild.exe as follows:

```
MSBuild.exe bootstrapper.msbuild <custom_variable1=custom_variable_value1>

custom_variable2=custom_variable_value2>...<custom_variablen=custom_variable_valuen>
```

The purpose is to know whether I have to launch another executable or not.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

You should start with the basics. The answer is found in [the official documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/msbuild-properties).

MSBuild calls these `properties` instead of variables.

In practice:

```
msbuild bootstrapper.msbuild /p:custom_variable1=custom_variable_value1
```

And in the MSBuild file you could use it as such:

```
<Target Name="MyTarget">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <custom_variable1 Condition="'$(custom_variable1)'==''">defaultValue</custom_variable1>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <Exec Condition="'$(custom_variable1)'=='someValue'" .../>
</Target>
```

This assigns a default value to the property if it doesn't exist or is empty, and only executes the `Exec` task if the value is equal to `someValue`.

Comment: This is the exact answer I was looking for ... `$(SolutionName)` seems to fail while the project is being loaded so that I have to do my check during the "execution"