# Can I include multiple publishing methods in my .NET Core csproj?

Tags: .net-core, azure-pipelines, csproj

I have a simple .NET Core `.csproj` for a project I want to deploy in two ways:

1. As a self-contained, trimmed, single-file binary (a portable `mytool.exe`, with no other files)
2. As an un-trimmed, multi-file DLL (`dotnet mytool.dll`, with some other supporting DLLs in the folder)

I want to do this because single-file .NET Core binaries are very slow to cold-start. I want this tool to be as portable as possible, so I need a single-file .NET Core binary, but I also want to let users call the much-faster `dotnet mytool.dll` if they don't need the portability.

I have configured my tool to build a self-contained, trimmed, single-file binary:

```xml
  <PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp3.1</TargetFramework>
    <RuntimeIdentifier>win10-x64</RuntimeIdentifier>
    <PublishReadyToRun>true</PublishReadyToRun>
    <PublishSingleFile>true</PublishSingleFile>
    <PublishTrimmed>true</PublishTrimmed>
  </PropertyGroup>
```

Is there an easy way to provide multiple "configurations" or "targets" that can be easily built from the command line (or in my case an ADO pipeline) so I can support my other configuration? E.g.:

```xml
  <!-- Other configuration (multi-file), somehow -->
  <PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp3.1</TargetFramework>
    <PublishReadyToRun>true</PublishReadyToRun>
  </PropertyGroup>
```

*Disclaimer: I work for Microsoft.*

Comment: You may pass all publish parameters directly to command line or make `PropertyGroup` condition based

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Building on Pavel's comment, I found some relevant information.

- MSDN [How to: Build the Same Source Files with Different Options](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/visualstudio/visual-studio-2015/msbuild/how-to-build-the-same-source-files-with-different-options?view=vs-2015)
- MSDN [MSBuild Properties](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/visualstudio/visual-studio-2015/msbuild/msbuild-properties1?view=vs-2015&redirectedfrom=MSDN)
- [How do I use custom variables in MSBuild scripts?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26328431/how-do-i-use-custom-variables-in-msbuild-scripts)

Then, following the [.NET application publishing overview](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/deploying/), I set up a custom property (`flavor`) to control the build:

```xml
  <!--
    Default flavor is SINGLEBINARY
    https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/visualstudio/visual-studio-2015/msbuild/how-to-build-the-same-source-files-with-different-options?view=vs-2015
  -->
  <PropertyGroup>
      <Flavor Condition="'$(Flavor)'==''">SINGLEBINARY</Flavor>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp3.1</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <!-- If flavor is SINGLEBINARY, output a standalone EXE -->
  <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Flavor)'=='SINGLEBINARY'">
    <RuntimeIdentifier>win10-x64</RuntimeIdentifier>
    <PublishReadyToRun>true</PublishReadyToRun>
    <PublishSingleFile>true</PublishSingleFile>
    <PublishTrimmed>true</PublishTrimmed>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <!-- If flavor is MULTIBINARY, output a more-typical dotnet DLL -->
  <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Flavor)'=='MULTIBINARY'">
    <!-- No specific options; the default publish works. -->
  </PropertyGroup>
```

I can now do separate builds and publishes based on this property:

```
dotnet build /p:flavor=singlebinary # single-binary; self-contained EXE for easy sharing
dotnet build /p:flavor=multibinary # multi-binary

dotnet publish --configuration Release /p:flavor=singlebinary
dotnet publish --configuration Release /p:flavor=multibinary
```